# elements of array are null

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working along with the BigNerdRanch ios app book. In the first chapter it makes a little quiz app with the questions hardcoded into code file. If the application runs successfully, it's supposed to say `displaying question: "What is blah blah?"` in the console, but when I run the app it says

```
displaying question: (null)
```

In other words, (null) is appearing instead of the question from the array.

No errors are showing when I compile. I wonder if it has to do with the fact that my XCode is using a `Main.storyboard` file rather than the xib and nib files, combined with the fact that the view controller uses a method that seems to expect a nib file, namely

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:
```

Any help would be appreciated. This is all the code.

iosQuizViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface iosQuizViewController : UIViewController
```

**iosQuizViewController.h**

```
{
    int currentQuestionIndex;

    NSMutableArray *questions;
    NSMutableArray *answers;

    IBOutlet UILabel *questionField;
    IBOutlet UILabel *answerField;
}

- (IBAction)showAnswer:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)showQuestion:(id)sender;

@end
```

iosQuizViewController.m

```
#import "iosQuizViewController.h"

@interface iosQuizViewController ()

@end

@implementation iosQuizViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        questions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        answers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [ questions addObject:@"What is 7 +7"];
        [ answers addObject:@"14"];

        [questions addObject:@"What is the capital of Vermont?"];
        [answers addObject:@"Montpelier"];

        [questions addObject:@"From what is cognac made?"];
        [answers addObject:@"Grapes"];

    }
    return self;
}

- (IBAction)showQuestion:(id)sender
{
    currentQuestionIndex++;
    if (currentQuestionIndex == [ questions count] ){
        currentQuestionIndex = 0;
    }
    NSString *question = [ questions objectAtIndex:currentQuestionIndex];
    NSLog(@"displaying question: %@", question);
    [questionField setText: question];
    [answerField setText:@"???"];

}

- (IBAction)showAnswer:(id)sender
{
    NSString *answer = [ answers objectAtIndex:currentQuestionIndex];

    [answerField setText:answer];
}


@end
```

Comment: Most likely the problem is because your `initWithNibName:bundle:` method is never called so `questions` is never initialized. Perhaps you should be using `initWithCoder:`.

Comment: My guess it that "questions" is nil, because it was never initialized.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the initWithNibName:bundle method and put that code inside viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    if (self)
    {
        // Create two arrays and make the pointers point to them
        questions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        answers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        // Add questions and answers to the array
        [questions addObject:@"What is 7 + 7?"];
        [answers addObject:@"14"];

        [questions addObject:@"What is the capital of Vermont?"];
        [answers addObject:@"Montpelier"];

        [questions addObject:@"What is cognac made from?"];
        [answers addObject:@"Grapes"];
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't forget to put [super viewDidLoad] at the top of the method.

Comment: And there is on need to check `self`.